# REGEX: Finding the correct occurrence order of some given special characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that would be able to find the correct occurrence order of

> * | . | # | 'any HTML element type' like 'p' or 'div'

**LIKE**

```
var regex = //Some regular expression;

var pattern_1 = "*p.class1#id1.class2";
pattern_1.match(regex); // Should print ['*','p','.','#','.']

var pattern_2 = "p.class1#id1.class2"; 
pattern_2.match(regex); //Should print ['p','.','#','.']

var pattern_3 = "p#id1.class1.class2";
pattern_3.match(regex); //Should print ['p','#','.','.']

var pattern_4 = "#id.class1.class2";
pattern_4.match(regex); //should print ['#id','.','.']

var pattern_5 = "*#id.class1.class2";
pattern_5.match(regex); //should print ['*','#','.','.']
```

I am trying my luck with `regex = /^\*?[a-zA-Z]*|\#|\./g` but it doesn't work

Comment: in order to match specific parts of a patten you need to use brackets `()` for group capturing.

Comment: @milkshake i don't think  `( )` is needed for String.match function it just searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

Comment: for the 4th pattern do you need only `#` or `#id` in output?

Comment: @Harry  only `#` and all  are optional i.e could repeat 0 or more times

Comment: of course you need the `()` to match specific parts of a string :D then what is returned to the array will be the whole match and then the matched groups.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off matching `#` and `.` along with their respective values and filtering the results afterwards:

```
 var regex = /\*|([#.]\w+)|(\w+)/g
 matches = pattern_1.match(regex).map(function(x) { return x.match(/^[#.]/) ? x.charAt(0) : x })
```

or remove the id/class names first, and then match:

```
 matches = pattern_1.replace(/([#.])\w+/g, "$1").match(/[.#*]|\w+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I have:

```
/(\*)|(\.)|([a-zA-Z]+)|(#)/g
```

the problem with this is that unless you specify all the possible html elements that you can capture like `div`, `span` etc then it will match all strings including class and id names.

Hope this helps anyway.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/Cppkd1ldjOitGUxm)