# Finding the correct occurrence order

Tags: php

I've a PHP string for example this string (haystack):

```
$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
```

Now I would like to set a PHP array in a order where the needle occurs in the string. So this is my needle:

```
$needle = array(",",".","|",":");
```

When searching for the needle in the `$text` string this should be the output:

```
Array (
   [0] => :
   [1] => ,
   [2] => .
   [3] => |
   [4] => :
)
```

Is this possible to achieve in PHP?

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181848/regex-finding-the-correct-occurrence-order-of-some-given-special-characters-in) but that's for JavaScript.

Comment: use `preg_match_all`  preg_match_all('/\:|\,|\||\)/i', '"here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)"', $result);

Comment: $result will give you as output you want

Comment: check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/18743579/1719246

Comment: check my corrected answer below(http://stackoverflow.com/a/18743573/2304043). It should solve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_split` could be handy here

```
$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$needles = array(",",".","|",":");
$chars = str_split($string);

$found = array();

foreach($chars as $char){
  if (in_array($char, $needles)){
    $found[] = $char ;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem on your code is that if there is more than one occurence of any needle, it will also appear more than once in the $found array. You should add " && !in_array($char, $found)" on the "if" condition.

Comment: @Scalpweb So, take a look at his result. This is exactly what he needs. `[0]` and `[4]` indexes.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly also this code was one of the fasted in Xdebug (and working in my set-up).

Answer (score 0):

This will get you your expected result:

```
     <?php
    $haystack= "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
    $needles = array(",",".","|",":");
    $result=array();
    $len = strlen($haystack) ;
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
        if(in_array($haystack[$i],$needles)) {
            $result[]=$haystack[$i];
        }
    }
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. th
is also | this one too :)";

preg_match_all('/\:|\,|\||\)/i', $string, $result); 

print_r(  array_shift($result) );
```

---

use `preg_match_all`

pattern `\:|\,|\||\)`

[**Working demo...**](https://eval.in/47920)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's make it just for fun

```
$string = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$needle = array(",",".","|",":");
$chars  = implode($needle);
$list   = array();

while (false !== $match = strpbrk($string, $chars)) {
    $list[] = $match[0];
    $string = substr($match, 1);
}

var_dump($list);
```

You can [see it working](https://eval.in/47913) - Read about [strpbrk](http://php.net/strpbrk)

### Explanation

`strpbrk` returns the string after the first matched character

#### Turn 1

```
$string = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";

// strpbrk matches ":"
$match = ": this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";

// Then, we push the first character to the list ":"
$list = array(':');

// Then we substract the first character from the string
$string = " this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
```

#### Turn 2

```
$string = " this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";

// strpbrk matches ","
$match = ", and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";

// Then, we push the first character to the list ","
$list = array(':', ',');

// Then we substract the first character from the string
$string = " and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
```

And so on until no match

#### Turn 5

```
$string = ")";

// strpbrk doesn't match and return false
$match = false;

// We get out of the while
```